# Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException

Tags: php, yii

in Yii framework i am facing an issue with deleting a record, info table contains a foriegn key which is linked with other tables. i am deleting the records sequence wise by deleting record from info table in last. Kindly help me solve this issue.

```
$model = StuMaster::findOne($id);
$address = StuAddress::findOne($model->stu_master_stu_address_id);
$info = StuInfo::findOne($model->stu_master_stu_info_id);
$pastacademics = StuPastacademics::findOne(['pastacad_studenid' => $info->stu_unique_id]);
$guardians = StuGuardians::findAll(['guardia_stu_master_id' => $model->stu_master_id]); 

$pastacademics->delete();
$model->delete();
$info->delete();
```

Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`whizzee_dihedblat`.`stu_info`, CONSTRAINT `stu_info_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`stu_info_stu_master_id`) REFERENCES `stu_master` (`stu_master_id`))
The SQL being executed was: DELETE FROM `stu_master` WHERE `stu_master_id`=61

Comment: Before deleting stu_master record you need to delete all references of that record. You're deleting past academics only, need to delete address and info records as well.

Comment: okay, i did that but now the error is changed

               The SQL being executed was: DELETE FROM `stu_address` WHERE `stu_address_id`=55

Comment: You've to remove reference data first before deleting the master record might be possible you have another associated table in which address id is foreign key..  If you don't want to remove reference records than you can use SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 . In my opinion its better to do soft delete instead of hard delete.

Comment: i would also prefer to go for soft delete, but is there a way to trace down the existing references as there are many tables listed in the db.

Comment: @RavindraBhalothia i have found the dependant tables where references are made by information_schema query and deleted those records first but still its showing the same error when i try to delete info record or master record.